# Android Gridview Buttons with a Cover Images on header

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to create an app similar like the attached picture. Hence I have read lots of articles from the website, like recyclerview with gridLayout, gridView, Tablelayout and so on. I am very new in developing android application.

So I am looking for a guideline that how could I proceed with this design, specifically the library or framework of this design. In my app I just want to have a cover photo on the heading. for example 3 or 4 images of the company which will be changed automatically with a swip view. And below this image I want to implement six button in gridview which is basically six option of this app. I do no want any scroll view in this app.

Now what would be the step by step work to do this app withoud complication. I have attached images here.The first one is the mockup of my app and the second one is the sample app in which way I want to implement.

[image: Mockup of my App option page]

[[image: Sample App as per expectation]

My XML code is for this page is-

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="demo.app.com.bluapp_client_and.ui.MainOptionPage"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#192832">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
  </LinearLayout>

 <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#125745">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2"/>

    </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

and for a single grid XML code is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="15dp"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:background="@drawable/option_background"
 >
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#f5edff" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Animated Slider at top try this way

```
dependencies {
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
        compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
}
```

**XML**

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
/>
```

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Now, for GridLayout i suggest to use

https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/grid-recyclerview-with-images-and-text.html

**EDIT**

As per your requirement you want to have six fixed grid, i suggest that use linear layouts with weightsum and weight.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".datasource.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

You can also use gridview

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2"/>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @ Aditya Vyas-Lakhan actually I do not want recycler view in my grid. I just want six fixed grid which will be adjusted on half of the screen. I have modified my answer with giving my code. But unfortunatly this is not fulfilling my requirement. I want to inplement the grid exactly same as given pictuew

Comment: @nowshinreza check my edited answer it is working for me

Comment: @Adyta But is not it possible with gridview

Comment: of course it is possible with gridview, but recyclerwith with gridlayoutmanager is better. that was my first suggestion.

Comment: I have simila gridview in my edited code. but the problem is that it does not fit to the layout. How can I achive the similar grid like image. I ma trying in evry process of grid. but nothing help me to achieve the sample image

Comment: check with different heights

Answer (score 0):

In your View ,

1. Use linear layout and divide it into 3-parts with weight sum as 3
2. use view pager with layout weight 1
3. use RecyclerView grid view with layout weight 2
   4 for indicator use any view pager indicator

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_onboarding"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <com.erbauen.App_intro.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

---

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try this one and let you know  as soon as possible

Comment: I have modified my question a little bit. the prpblem is that i do not want to get recyclerview in my grid. I just want 6 fixed grid which servs as a option button. similar like the sample picture. but with my code I cannot fit the grid inside the framelayout. it shows some emply space at bottom

Comment: you can keep the top view pager, Instead of recycler view  you go with linear layout  .... But Recycler makes you life easier in terms of handling the click events and loading the multiple view in effective way .... With respect to the height ,make the child layout height to wrap content